# How can you map and cast unknown types in Java when using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, types, casting

I'm using reflection to map getters from one class to setters in another i.e. I have form classes used by stuts1 for display mostly text (Strings) and I have pure Java objects used by the back end which holds the values in their specific type.  I've currently got the mapping working between the getters and setters which was easy but I'm having trouble with the mixed types.  I'm using the parameter type from the setter to see what's expected and so I need to determine the type of the object from the getter and cast it some how to the expected type.

E.g.

```
HomePageForm  ->   HomePageData 
Name="Alexei" ->   String name; (Maps correctly) 
Age="22"      ->   int age;     (Needs casting from string to int and visa-vera in reverse)
```

The following is my code so far

```
/**
     * Map the two given objects by reflecting the methods from the mapTo object and finding its setter methods.  Then 
     * find the corresponding getter method in  the mapFrom class and invoke them to obtain each attribute value.  
     * Finally invoke the setter method for the mapTo class to set the attribute value.  
     * 
     * @param mapFrom The object to map attribute values from
     * @param mapTo   The object to map attribute values to
     */
    private void map(Object mapFrom, Object mapTo) {
        Method [] methods = mapTo.getClass().getMethods();
        for (Method methodTo : methods) {
            if (isSetter(methodTo)) {
                try {
                    //The attribute to map to setter from getter
                    String attName = methodTo.getName().substring(3);

                    //Find the corresponding getter method to retrieve the attribute value from
                    Method methodFrom = mapFrom.getClass().getMethod("get" + attName, new Class<?>[0]);

                    //If the methodFrom is a valid getter, set the attValue
                    if (isGetter(methodFrom)) {
                        //Invoke the getter to get the attribute to set
                        Object attValue = methodFrom.invoke(mapFrom, new Object[0]);

                        Class<?> fromType = attValue.getClass();

                        //Need to cast/parse type here
                        if (fromType != methodTo.getParameterTypes()[0]){
                            //!!Do something to case/parse type!!
                        } //if

                        //Invoke the setter to set the attribute value
                        methodTo.invoke(mapTo, attValue);
                    } //if
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Constants.APP_LOGGER).fine("Exception in DataFormMappingService.map: "
                                                              + "IllegalArgumentException" + e.getMessage());
                    continue;
                }
            } //if
        } //for
    } //map
```

Thanks in advance,
Alexei  Blue.

Comment: Try Dozer (http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/simpleproperty.html) it handles this kind of thing automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a better solution in the end:

```
    /**
     * Map to given objects taking into account the inclusion and exclusion sets.
     * 
     * @param mapFrom The object to map attribute values from
     * @param mapTo   The object to map attribute values to
     */
    private void map(Object mapFrom, Object mapTo)
    {
        setMapFilter(mapFrom, mapTo);

        for (Method sMethod : filterMap.keySet())
        {            
            try
            {
               //Find the corresponding getter method to retrieve the attribute value from
                Method gMethod = filterMap.get(sMethod);

                //Invoke the getter to get the attribute to set
                Object attValue = gMethod.invoke(mapFrom, new Object[0]);

                //Get the mapping types and check their compatibility, if incompatible convert attValue type to toType
                Class<?> fromType = gMethod.getReturnType();
                Class<?> toType   = sMethod.getParameterTypes()[0];

                if(!toType.isAssignableFrom(fromType) && Objects.isNotNull(attValue))
                {
                    attValue = parseType(attValue, toType);
                } //if

                //Invoke the setter to set the attribute value
                sMethod.invoke(mapTo, attValue);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(Constants.APP_LOGGER).fine("Exception in DataFormMappingService.map: "
                                                          + "IllegalArgumentException " + e.getMessage());
                continue;
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(Constants.APP_LOGGER).fine("Exception in DataFormMappingService.map: "
                                                          + "IllegalAccessException " + e.getMessage());
                continue;
            }
            catch (InvocationTargetException e)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(Constants.APP_LOGGER).fine("Exception in DataFormMappingService.map: "
                                                          + "InvocationTargetException " + e.getMessage());
                continue;
            }
        } //for each
    } //map

    /**
     * Refactored method to parse an object, attValue, from it's unknown type to the type expected.
     * 
     * @param attValue The attribute value to parse
     * @param type     The type expected/to convert to
     * @return         The attribute value in the expected type, null otherwise
     */
    private Object parseType(Object attValue, Class<?> type)
    {
        Object newAttValue = null;

        if (isLiteral(type))
        {
            newAttValue = attValue.toString();
        }
        else if (isByte(type))
        {
            newAttValue = Byte.valueOf(attValue.toString());
        }
        else if (isInt(type))
        {
            newAttValue = Integer.valueOf(attValue.toString());
        }
        else if (isShort(type))
        {
            newAttValue = Short.valueOf(attValue.toString());
        }
        else if (isLong(type))
        {
            newAttValue = Long.valueOf(attValue.toString());
        }
        else if (isFloat(type))
        {
            newAttValue = Float.valueOf(attValue.toString());
        }
        else if (isDouble(type))
        {
            newAttValue = Double.valueOf(attValue.toString());
        }
        else if (isBoolean(type))
        {
            newAttValue = Boolean.valueOf(attValue.toString());
        } //if-else if*

        return newAttValue;
    } //parseType
```

It's cleaner than my original solution but essentially when mapping, a filter is built of methods to map which is simply looped through and then mapped.  The parse method just checks types and uses the valueOf method on an Object.toString() which works for standard Java types.

Cheers,

Alexei Blue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a hero in reflection, but my guess is that `int` is a primitive data type and your `attValue` is of type `Object`.

Can you try and change the type of age to `Integer` so that it can be cast to `Object`

Comment: Hi Molske I think the problem is that the invoke method unwraps and attempts to convert Objects into primitive types but because it doesn't know whether 22 should be an int or a long it just leaves it as a String

Comment: I changed it to an Integer but it still throws IllegalArgumentException.  Essentially to the object from the Form is retrieved which is a String and then the data object expects it to be an Integer/int for internal use.  So to convert it to an Integer I guess I'd need to use Integer.valueOf?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, @Molske is spot on.  The problem is the promoting of the `int` return value to be an `Integer` and then this comparison:

```
if (fromType != methodTo.getParameterTypes()[0])
```

I just ran a quick test of your code and I get the exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<class java.lang.Integer> but was:<int>
```

Instead of `fromType`, if you compare against `methodFrom.getReturnType()` then the code should work:

```
if (methodFrom.getReturnType() != methodTo.getParameterTypes()[0])
```

Here's the test I was working with:

```
@Test
public void testException() throws Exception {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    for (Method methodTo : Bar.class.getMethods()) {
        if (methodTo.getName().startsWith("set")) {
            String attName = methodTo.getName().substring(3);
            Method methodFrom = Foo.class.getMethod("get" + attName);
            if (methodFrom != null && methodFrom.getName().startsWith("get")) {
                Object attValue = methodFrom.invoke(foo);
                // this ignores the auto-boxing issues
                assertEquals(methodFrom.getReturnType(),
                    methodTo.getParameterTypes()[0]);
                methodTo.invoke(bar, attValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
private static class Foo {
    public int getFoo() { return 1; }
}
private static class Bar {
    public void setFoo(int i) { System.out.println("i = " + i); }
}
```

Comment: Hey Gray, I think I've been a bit unclear with the problem I'm having.  The problem is that the types between form and data aren't the same e.g. say getFoo in Foo returns a String instead and setFoo remains the same.  This is where my mapping method falls apart a bit, how ever I've written a small parser method which does the trick for now, it's just not very dynamic atm